# How to save file and corresponding url?

Tags: files, url

Suppose, I download a book from a URL(using `wget` or other tool). I want to save the book and the URL, so that I can know from where I downloaded the book.

I don't use different file. I want to save the URL inside the book file(may as one attribute of the book file).

Comment: TO store it inside the file we need to know the file format of the book (pdf?). Then you could use tools to add meta information to that format. Easier and universal approach: How about adding the URL to the file name?

Comment: It depends on the book format: If the book is in epub format, for example, it's just a zip file, so you can `echo` the URL from `wget` into a file, and add this file to the epub book file. You can also add it as a HTML comment to the `opf` file inside the epub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like a log file work:

```
wget -nv -o wget.log -O "save-file" "URL"
```

And if you want to keep adding to the log file instead of overwriting it:

```
wget -nv -a wget.log -O "save-file" "URL"
```

What you get is something like:

```
2017-05-15 16:46:58 URL:https://some.url/ [file size] -> "save-file" [1]
```

What is happening here:

`-nv` : "not verbose" output. Just the details, not everything.

`-a wget.log` : "append" info to the log file (in this case, "wget.log").

`-o wget.log` : Creates a new log file (old one is removed, if found).

The rest you most likely know.